# Facebook Box Count Like Button Vertical Alignment

Tags: html, css, alignment

[image]

I'm using this kind of button. How to align that to other buttons (G+, Twitter, etc) vertically?

Because `vertical-align: top` doesn't align correctly for this kind of box count.

```
<div class=fb-like data-layout=box_count></div>
<a class=twitter-share-button href=//twitter.com/share data-count=vertical data-dnt=true>Tweet</a>
<div class=g-plusone data-size=tall></div>
```

Comment: Post the source code of your attempt.

Comment: 1: Do you have something against double quotes? 2: There are no predefined attributes `"data-layout", "data-count", "data-dnt", "data-size"`, so I have no idea what they do (what you intend for them to do). They can be used by javascript, but you have not posted any. This source code does nothing, so I can't answer your question.

Comment: These attributes and quotes have nothing to do with the question and CSS. The question is about how to align this kind of Facebook button to other buttons.

Comment: To align images vertically (one under the other), you just put them in divs. Can I assume you have tried that? Because otherwise I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: 3 like buttons are in a horizontal row: Facebook, Twitter, Google+. I need to align that vertically to one bottom line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.fb-like{
position:relative;
top:-20px; //adjust to your needs
}
```

`vertical-align` works for `inline` and `inline-block` elements I guess, you should put this style on the parent element not on `.fb-like`

Comment: I thought about the same. Seems it's logical in this case. Thanks!